# Recovering Jenkins admin account overshadowed by GitHub OAuth

Tags: authentication, github, jenkins, oauth-2.0, jenkins-plugins

The use case is a `sudo` for a dual-role user who wants to switch user accounts to perform Jenkins administrative tasks when no GitHub account is authorized as a local Jenkins admin and GitHub OAuth Plugin manages authentication (overshadowing Jenkins built-in authentication form).

*More info*

A power user with two roles (Jenkins admin and DevOps) wants to perform some administrative task (like adding an access token to Jenkins keyring), but none of the linked GitHub accounts (that can be authenticated by Jenkins using its GitHub OAuth Plugin) is authorized as Jenkins admin (using Matrix Authorization Strategy). Is the admin account effectively locked out, because Jenkins GitHub OAuth Plugin does not let us log in with local Jenkins admin rights? If so, then shouldn't this situation be prevented by the GitHub OAuth Plugin, ensuring that at least one GitHub user has retained Jenkins admin role?

Side note: out of all alternatives such as (over)shadowing, hiding, or obscuring, the first sounded the most exciting, but feel free to fix the term if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to turn off security, i.e. escalate to admin... using Jenkins own interface. But wait, there's more: I was led there by... Jenkins' security tip.

Just go to:

```
https://<JENKINS_URL>/configureSecurity/
```

(then change Security Realm to "None" and Authorization to "Anyone can do anything").

Key take-away: never run Jenkins without proper air-gapping.